# Is the jQuery version I can use limited by the .NET version I am using (in Sharepoint apps)?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, .net-3.5, version

I asked this on the [jQuery forum](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/is-the-jquery-version-i-can-use-limited-by-the-net-version-i-am-using-in-sharepoint-apps), but was told it would be better to ask elsewhere, so here goes:

Very soon (starting next week), I am going to be doing Sharepoint 2010 development, which uses .NET 3.5.

JavaScript / jQuery is part of this world, or can be (client-side code). But are there limitations on which versions of jQuery can be used with particular versions of .NET?

IOW, is there a chart somewhere that shows which jQuery versions are compatible with the various versions of .NET?

Or can I use the latest jQuery version regardless of the .NET version in play?

Comment: make sure you read the comment on the accepted answer for some more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. They are not connected in any way.

You can use whichever version of jQuery you desire.

---

**Update**
As correctly pointed out in the comments below, SP2010 renders in IE8 mode and jQuery 2.x.x is not supported by IE8.

Comment: The answer is not entirely correct. It is true for .NET apps, but Sharepoint 2010 Out of the Box renders in ie8 compatibility mode. jQuery 2.0 is not compatible with ie8,  so I would use the 1.x versions or modify the masterpages to render in edge.

Comment: @Luis Correct, I forgot about that detail. Thank you for pointing it out. Have updated my answer.